# How to order results based on number of search term matches?

Tags: search, mysql

I am using the following InnoDB tables in mysql to describe records that can have multiple searchtags associated with them:

```
TABLE records
    ID
    title
    desc

TABLE searchTags
    ID
    name

TABLE recordSearchTags
    recordID
    searchTagID
```

To SELECT records based on arbitrary search input, I have a statement that looks sort of like this:

```
SELECT 

    recordSearchTags.recordID

FROM 

    recordSearchTags

LEFT JOIN searchTags 

ON recordSearchTags.searchTagID = searchTags.ID 

WHERE 

    searchTags.name LIKE CONCAT('%','$search1','%') OR
    searchTags.name LIKE CONCAT('%','$search2','%') OR
    searchTags.name LIKE CONCAT('%','$search3','%') OR
    searchTags.name LIKE CONCAT('%','$search4','%');
```

I'd like to ORDER this resultset, so that rows that match with more search terms are displayed in front of rows that match with fewer search terms.

For example, if a row matches all 4 search terms, it will be top of the list.  A row that matches only 2 search terms will be somewhere in the middle.  And a row that matches just one search term will be at the end.

Any suggestions on what is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be feasible to grab all the results and process them outside of the database?  Depending on how many rows in your DB it may be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Replaced answer, since fulltext isn't an option*

Alright, it's not pretty, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
ORDER BY (searchTags.name LIKE CONCAT('%','$search1','%') 
          + searchTags.name LIKE CONCAT('%','$search2','%')
          + searchTags.name LIKE CONCAT('%','$search3','%')
          + searchTags.name LIKE CONCAT('%','$search4','%'))
DESC;
```

`LIKE` returns `1` on a match or `0` if there is no match, so you should just be able to add the results together.

Comment: Unfortunatley the tables are InnoDB.  I was hoping not to have to create and maintain separate MyISAM tables just for search purposes...

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that fulltext didn't work on InnoDB. Wow. Let me look around a bit and then I'll try to edit my answer to something that's actually relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very pretty but one way would be to union the 4 likes in 4 statements like

```
select ... where  searchTags.name LIKE CONCAT('%','$search1','%')
union 
select ...
```

and so on.  Wrap that in a:

```
select recordSearchTags.recordID, count(*) from (<inner unions>)
group by recordSearchTags.recordID 
order by count(*)
```